# How can I make more secure in my system? I can see some intruder trying to hack my web application

Tags: php, linux

I can see in my application log some 404 error message like below

```
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:50 --> 404 Page Not Found: Robotstxt/index
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:51 --> 404 Page Not Found: Xmlrpcphp/index
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:51 --> 404 Page Not Found: Blog/robots.txt
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:52 --> 404 Page Not Found: Blog/index
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:52 --> 404 Page Not Found: Wordpress/index
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:52 --> 404 Page Not Found: Wp/index
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:52 --> 404 Page Not Found: Robotstxt/index
ERROR - 2018-09-07 05:31:53 --> 404 Page Not Found: Administrator/index.php
```

This happening every day. I have doubt somebody trying to hack my system. because I am sure, we are not using open source library or system.

Even I checked server log also, I can see some IP address  but this address keep on changing every time, so i am not able to choose IP blocker

Server Log:

```
194.79.31.99 - - [07/Sep/2018:05:31:50 +0400] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 1130 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.32"
194.79.31.99 - - [07/Sep/2018:05:31:50 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.32"
194.79.31.99 - - [07/Sep/2018:05:31:51 +0400] "GET /xmlrpc.php?rsd HTTP/1.1" 404 1130 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.32"
194.79.31.99 - - [07/Sep/2018:05:31:51 +0400] 
"GET /blog/robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 1130 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.32"
194.79.31.99 - - [07/Sep/2018:05:31:51 +0400] 

Platform: PHP/Mysql
Server : linux
Already I protect my directory listing by htaccess.
```

How can I make more secure in my system. please help me...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This is why we use a reverse proxy  ... lol ... stupid bots.

Comment: This is goign into sysadmin territory, not programming.  That said, since I do both, I'd configure `fail2ban` to deal with multiple attempts and 404 errors to known attack URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal your system gets attacked when it comes online. Intruders are running scripts to test for known vulnerabilities. It has nothing to do with open source or closed source libraries, both can be safe or vulnerable.

What you must do when you go on the internet with a machine is having a good professional system-admin check and maintain your machine. This is not something that someone with no deep knowledge of system-security can do.